# How to disable the default browser dialog with firefox -no-remote -P options

Tags: firefox

I have a profile called "some profile"

I invoke it from the command line like this:

```
firefox -no-remote -P "some profile"
```

Each time I do so I get this annoying popup:

[image]

Clicking on **Don't ask me again** and then clicking on **Use Firefox as my default browser**, closing the browser and then executing the above command again causes it to popup again.

How do I get it to stop doing that?

Firefox version info:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 on x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
```

Reference material that was not helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

backref: id:6375b43a-e002-49f3-8855-56a534571d50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go into `about:config` and change the `browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser` configuration option from true to false.
See the comment at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1134105#c6 for the reasoning.

Comment: I posted a bug report to http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2913719

Comment: That's a forum run by users. Use this to report bugs to developers: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/